# Finding a bijection and using the Schröder-Bernstein to prove same cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been asked to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ and the interval $(-\infty,0)$ have the same cardinality using two methods, one being find a  bijection and the other to use the Schröder-Bernstein theorem.

How am I able to achieve this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: The Schroder Bernstein theorem is obviously the easier route: you just have to find two injections, one of which is obvious. Finding a bijection may require a little ingenuity. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm sort of just stuck on how to complete either. Most of what I've done is write out the method and attempt to wrap my head around it. To find the injection, do you choose any old function? Or have I gotten this completely wrong?

Comment: Any old function will do, provided it is injective. It does not have to be continuous. For example you might take $x\to-\frac{1}{x}$ for the positive reals greater than 1. That maps them one-one onto $(-1,0)$, leaving you plenty of room to accommodate 0 and the negative reals.

Comment: Then you could map $[0,1]$ to $[-6,-5]$ by $x\to x-6$. You would then need a final piece to deal with the negative numbers.

Comment: When you say it "maps them one-to-one onto (-1,0)", what do you mean by (-1,0)?

Comment: The open interval $-1<x<0$.

Comment: This may be frustrating to hear but I still don't fully understand what is happening..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your comments it may be worth saying a few things about infinite sets. For finite sets we are used to deciding if they are the same size by counting them. One way of looking at that is that they have the same size if there is a bijection between them.

But the finite case also suggests that if there is an injection $f:A\to B$ which is *not* a bijection then $A$ is strictly smaller than $B$. That is false for infinite sets. The easiest case to look at is $A$ the positive even integers and $B$ the positive integers. The inclusion map is obviously an injection and not onto. But the correspondence $2n\leftrightarrow n$ shows that there is a bijection between the two sets.

So for infinite sets all a non-onto injection $A\to B$ allows us to conclude is that the size of $B$ is at least as big as that of $A$.

The other point to bear in mind is that infinite sets are not all the same size. The classic argument there is the Cantor diagonalisation argument which shows that there are more reals than integers (if you could list all the reals, then take a real which differs from the $n$th in the list in the $n$th place of decimals gives a contradiction).

However, the Schroder-Bernstein theorem gives us that if there are injections $A\to B$ and $B\to A$, then $A$ and $B$ are the same size.

So turning to the question, you have the obvious inclusion $(-\infty,0)\to\mathbb{R}$ as one injection. For the other you could take $f:\mathbb{R}\to(-\infty,0)$ defined by $f(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$ for $x>1$ and $x-5$ for $x\le1$. That maps the reals $>1$ onto $(-1,0)$ and the reals $\le1$ onto $(\infty,-4]$. It is obviously an injection. So the Schroder-Bernstein theorem gives the required result.

Alternatively, you could slightly modify $f(x)$ by defining $f(x)=x-2$ for $x\le1$. That makes $f$ a bijection and so establishes equal size directly.